# how to get all the users/groups/service account who has access to a table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
from pprint import pprint

from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='keys/key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource='project-answer-379305', body={},).execute()


pprint(response)
```

this gets me all the users a project not the table.
I did try the object privileges

```
SELECT *
FROM mycompany.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES
WHERE object_schema = "mydataset" AND object_name = "testdata"
```

If a user has access to a dataset level this query does not list it (in grantee column) but if a user has access only to that table it does list, and also this does not list the service account(I can query to that table from python using a service account cant see the service account in grantee column). Is there a way where I could get all the users/groups/service accounts of a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will meet your requirement.

The approach is basically using google cloud asset inventory api with batchget method.
https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/effectiveIamPolicies/batchGet

if you navigate to below url, the page should also launch a "try this method pop screen" see screenshot below.

in the scope section enter below value in below format:

```
scope = projects/ENTERYOURPROJECTNAME
names = //bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/YOURPROJECTNAME/datasets/YOURDATASET
```

and then "execute", this will ask you to login with your console credentials, once done, you should see a response as in image sample json output

[image]

finally, if this answers, please mark my post as answered:-)

```
{
  "policyResults": [
    {
      "fullResourceName": "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/YOURPROJCETNAME/datasets/mydataset",
      "policies": [
        {
          "attachedResource": "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/YOURPROJECTNAME/datasets/YOURDATASET",
          "policy": {
            "bindings": [
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.dataEditor",
                "members": [
                  "projectEditor:YOURPROJECTNAME"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.dataOwner",
                "members": [
                  "projectOwner:YOURPROJECTNAME",
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.dataViewer",
                "members": [
                  "projectViewer:YOURPROJECTNAME"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "attachedResource": "//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/YOURPROJECTNAME",
          "policy": {
            "bindings": [
              {
                "role": "roles/artifactregistry.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-artifactregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.admin",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:svc-looker-bigquery@YOURPROJECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname.lastname@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.dataEditor",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.jobUser",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquery.readSessionUser",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/bigquerydatatransfer.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudbuild.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudscheduler.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudtasks.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/cloudtranslate.admin",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:svc-looker-bigquery@YOURPROJECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/composer.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/compute.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/connectors.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-connectors.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/container.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/containerregistry.ServiceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/datacatalog.admin",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/datacatalog.categoryAdmin",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/dataflow.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/dataform.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-dataform.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/datafusion.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-datafusion.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/datalineage.admin",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/datapipelines.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-datapipelines.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/dataproc.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@dataproc-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/editor",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com",
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com",
                  "serviceAccount:YOURPROJECTNAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/eventarc.eventReceiver",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/eventarc.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-eventarc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/integrations.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-integrations.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/owner",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname_1.lastname_1@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname_2.lastname_2s@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/pubsub.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/resourcemanager.projectOwnerInvitee",
                "members": [
                  "user:firstname_2.lastname_2@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/run.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/source.reader",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-bihag-trfm-yourprojectname@YOURPROJECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/storage.admin",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:123456789101@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/viewer",
                "members": [
                  "user:bihag.kashikar@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname_2.lastname_2s@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname_2.lastname_2@yourorg.com.au",
                  "user:firstname.lastname@yourorg.com.au"
                ]
              },
              {
                "role": "roles/workflows.serviceAgent",
                "members": [
                  "serviceAccount:service-123456789101@gcp-sa-workflows.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is working fine for the users who have access to/from a project/dataset/tables level, I'm able to get all the users, but if a user has access from/to folder/organization level this fails to get/display the users who have access to it. Is there any method where I could get the users for that to(i.e from folder/organization user access to the table).

Comment: hi there, have you tried changing the scope to  "organizations/123"), a folder number (such as "folders/123"), to do this you will need to be org admin(this is a guess)