# GCP BigQuery - Get dataset permissions including inherited permissions (API)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api

I am trying to get via GCP BigQuery API (currently testing in their API Explorer) the dataset access permissions but it seems like I am only getting permissions which **are not inheritied**

The method I am using is `datasets.get` ([link here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get))

Is there an option to include additional parameter, use a different endpoint or add more permissions so that I can get inheritied permissions as well (and from where it was inheritied? e.g organization -> folder -> project)?

I hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

I tried getting the inheritied permissions of a dataset but only got those that are not inherited (project level)

Comment: see my answer in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820185/how-to-get-all-the-users-groups-service-account-who-has-access-to-a-table-in-big/75821048#75821048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012705/bigquery-command-line-find-all-tables-across-all-datasets-with-a-specific-regex/76012986#76012986) hope this helps